# Are scores in the comments of closed questions counted towards the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, closed-questions, data-explorer, comment-voting, comment-badges

I recently (yesterday) got more than 5 scores in a few of my comments, but while the question was closed.

Will this be counted for my pundit badge progress? When I checked my progress in the Data Explorer today, the comments in which I scored more than 5 and were closed were not in the list with my other >5 score comments.

Is it such that the scores for closed question comment is not counted?

Comment: If a question is closed, everything in that question is still calculated. Whether or not it's deleted is a different matter, and one I'm not sure about.

Comment: ok.. and may be the data eexplorer is not updated(synced) and  thus is not listing my comments rite??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question being closed has absolutely no effect on comments for that badge. Comments which are *deleted* do not count towards the badge any longer.

Also, keep in mind that Data Explorer is only updated once a week, so your newer activity will not appear there right away.

Comment: yup... i thought i read somewhere that it will be updated once a day around midnight... anyways my bad.. thanks.. :)...